# Push Notifications Certificates Question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, push-notification

Push notifications are not working for the App Store version of my app, while the development version does work. After spending an hour looking through my code, I realized that it's probably the certificate I am using to sign my app! Before, I was using a wildcard App ID to generate a certificate (com.Apple.*). If I use the correct App ID, do you think it would start working? Again, everything works with the development certificate. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a fully qualified provisioning profile to add push notifications to your App.  If you switch to the correct App ID, your notifications should work fine. Remember though, to make sure the App IDs & bundle IDs match exactly.

Comment: Great, just wanted to make sure before I waited through the review process again. Thanks!